# From texture painting to UV map

Tags: uv, texture-painting, vertex-colors

I'm a newbie and I have a hypothetical question that is interested in me.

For example, the man has a 3D-model and texture painting therefore he has a UV map.
The man detects a mistake in UV and decides to remake the UV map fully.

The question: Are there tools to help the man go back and remake UV, and transpose all textures (doesn't redraw them) to a new UV map?

Let's say, it would be nice if the man can transpose texture paint to vertex paint. But it can be not so quality if 3D-model has less resolution than an image of texture paint. And I have no ideas it possible or not.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at baking? You can bake from one UV map to another I think....

Comment: @CraigDJones cool idea, I try it. I think I need two same models with different UV. Do I right understand?

Comment: No, you can bake from one texture image to a new one using two different UV map schemes using a Cycles Emission shader. I will try to set up a simple example when I can take a break, or you can look for existing examples here on SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start the example with creating a texture from a box mapped image texture set to blend as a way to get something baked to the initial uv map.
[image]
I've set up an image texture to bake to as a target and am using an emission shader to avoid shadow
[image]
I leave the image target disconnected and selected before baking Emit
[image]
Here you see in the UV editor the newly baked pixels on the target image in relation to the UV map, save this image now to disk
[image]
Here we set up a New UV map and set it to viewable, then unwrap to a new scheme
[image]
Here we check the new mapping to a new image texture target so you can see we are not dealing with the previous UV map - reference the new map in the UV node
[image]
We need to reverse the connection so that we leave the target image node disconnected and still selected and then press bake emit
[image]
Our result on the new UV map is visible now, and we have gone from generated texture coordinate image texture to UV mapped image texture to a second UV mapped image texture. Save you result image to disk if satisfied with the mapping.
[image]

Comment: I see. Thanks. Two questions if I can: 1. Why we certainly use Emission node (not Diffuse in that case or other shader). 2. In your case, you use one object for bake if to use two objects as I said before - what will happen? Is it a mistake?

Comment: 1. Emission eliminates the need to create a light scheme that will not adversely affect the diffuse texture - try to bake the diffuse instead, and you will get either solid black or badly shadowed image texture instead of the exact same texture. 2. If you bake from one object to the other, then you also deal with distance and baking from selected to active object - which introduces more problems switching between selections. If you don't have to, then it is less work this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for fully explain. Unfortunately, I still can't vote up this answer.

Comment: I try to bake through Diffuse Shader. I set Bake Type to Diffuse (not Combined) and turn off Direct and Indirect (set only Color) and use Diffuse Shader (not Emission Shader). The result is good. It looks like I am baking albedo (no shadow, no light). It seems direct/indirect light interfere correctly bake. What do you think about this method?

Comment: Unfortunately, in both cases (Emission Shader, Diffuse Shader) some color lost. I bake mono color. Original color is #41FF6A after bake color at new UV is #40FE69.

Comment: If your color is changing, then you need to look at your Color Management. Settings there will affect your bake.